# How can I move col2 rows with arrows into Col1 without using union

Tags: oracle

```
col1     col2
FA         W
FA         W
FA         W
0007041    <-FA
0007382L   <-W
0008748    <-SC
```

How can I move col2 rows with arrows into Col1 without using union

Comment: What's your mean about  `into Col1`?

Comment: Are the arrows actually part of the column values or just for illustration? Please edit your question to clarify that, your logic for 'moving' the values, whether you mean a table update or just as part of a query; and also show the result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you've said, you should use `CASE` (or `DECODE`, whichever you prefer - `CASE` is easier to read and maintain) to *transform* all those 'IF' statements (you wrote in words) into SQL, such as

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2)
  2       as (select 'FA', 'W' from dual
  3           union all
  4           select 'FA', 'W' from dual
  5           union all
  6           select 'FA', 'W' from dual
  7           union all
  8           select '0007041', 'FA' from dual
  9           union all
 10           select '0007382L', 'W' from dual
 11           union all
 12           select '0008748', 'SC' from dual)
 13  select col1, col2,
 14    case when col1 = 'FA' and col2 = 'W' then 'FA'
 15         when col2 = 'FA' then 'FA'
 16         when col2 = 'W' then 'W'
 17         when col2 = 'SC' then 'SC'
 18         else col1
 19    end new_col1
 20    from test;

COL1     COL2       NEW_COL1
-------- ---------- --------
FA       W          FA
FA       W          FA
FA       W          FA
0007041  FA         FA
0007382L W          W
0008748  SC         SC

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, so very much.